# How do you format BEGIN ... END statements using PDO's with SQL?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

This works fine:

```
...
$sql = "INSERT INTO person (`name`, `age`)
        VALUES ('John', 34);";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
...
```

But this gives an error:

```
...
$sql = "BEGIN
            INSERT INTO person (`name`, `age`)
            VALUES ('John', 34);
        END;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
...
```

The error is:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

And more specifically:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO person (`name`, `age`)
```

I know that the BEGIN ... END is unnecessary in this contrived example, but why does it not work?

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: BEGIN and END  keywords are using in my*?sql function not in query.....

Answer (score 1):

In PDO, like in any other API, **you run separate queries using separate API calls:**

Given the END keyword makes no sense and assuming you meant COMMIT,

```
$conn->query("BEGIN");
$conn->query("INSERT INTO person (`name`, `age`) VALUES ('John', 34)");
$conn->query("COMMIT");
```

However, you have to keep in mind that

- there is no point in running a transaction for a single query
- there is no point in using a prepared statement if you bind no data to it